# Uninstall Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wubi, windows-7, uninstall

I want to uninstall my Ubuntu 12.04 (installed using Wubi). My Ubuntu is on one of partitions that I don't want to delete my partition.i using win 7.
And I don't use grub

Comment: OP indicated in the comment to one of the answers that it is an WUBI install.

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Ubuntu (if you installed it using Wubi), simply go into **Programs and Features** from Control Panel in Windows 7, look for Ubuntu and uninstall it, just like you would uninstall any program in Windows *(see image below)*. It will not delete the partition, it will only delete the files that it created on that partition.

[image]

If this did not work, or for more information about Wubi uninstallation (or general Wubi information), click [**here**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#Uninstallation)

Answer (score 0):

from windows7 manually delete `home` folder

now, if you have grub as your boot manager **its not advisable to delete anything else.**

if your boot manager is the windows one you can delete manually the other folders of ubuntu

**for future reference:**  use `Gparted` to organize your hard drive before installing any OS so this wont happen again.

Answer (score -1):

From Win 7 simply format the hard drive.

Comment: I told u I have files on that hard drive.

Comment: Was Ubuntu installed from within Windows using WUBI.EXE?

Comment: Yes I install Ubuntu by using wubi

Comment: With a live cd enter in the partition, save files on a usb drive and then erase the partition from win7. I always do in this way.

Comment: All he wants to do is uninstall Wubi, a simple fix via the Control Panel. He stated in his original question that there were files he wanted to keep, so he didn't want to reformat the entire partition.

Comment: The question is bad written..